# Spring Integration DSL Http Inbound Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I tried to use the following code and I got as a response: Status: 405 Method Not Allowed. Here is my Http request: http://localhost:8090/services/test?name=test.
What's wrong with the code or http request?

```
@Bean
      public IntegrationFlow httpInternalServiceFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Http.inboundGateway("/services/test")
                        .requestMapping(r -> r.params("name")
                        .methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                        .payloadExpression("#requestParams.name"))
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Please, turn on DEBUG logic level for the `org.springframework` category to see what's going on with your request on the server. You might have some Servlet `Filter` up front of that HTTP Inbound Gateway. On the other hand it isn't clear if you have `@EnableIntegration` or not...

Comment: Received a request to uri [/services/test] that should not be sampled [false]
No parent span present - creating a new span
Successfully completed request
Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4f7f63c4

Comment: Retrieving delivery for Consumer@3bb8d847: , channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel, conn: Proxy@5a9d5e2 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@32a4284d , acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
The request with uri [/services/test] hasn't been handled by any of Sleuth's components. That means that most likely you're using custom HandlerMappings and didn't add Sleuth's TraceHandlerInterceptor. Sleuth will create a span to ensure that the graph of calls remains valid in Zipkin
Detaching the span Trace since the response was unsuccessful

Comment: ??? How that Sleuth concern is related to your question? Maybe you can share simple Boot application to play from our side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to come to the root of the problem. 
spring-boot-starter-amqp maps servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*] and due to the fact that I have registered my endpoing to /services/test application came to a conflict